# How to share file between apps without file section interface

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, file-sharing, data-sharing

I am trying to make an app that can easily keep sending files to different apps(whichever the user is running currently), when those apps make request to my app for files.

I was going through this link [Sharing a file in Android](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file) , [Sharing simple data in android](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send) and also [Sharecompat Blog](https://www.niyati.com/blog/android-sharecompat/). 
In these links they use a chooser interface to select target apps which I don't want.
My goal is that those other apps can communicate with my app without any clicks or selection.
And In response I can provide them the necessary files.

But I couldn't find anything which can help me build my desired app.
How Can I do it?

Please, Any suggesstions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212994/discussion-on-question-by-abhishek-kumar-how-to-share-file-between-apps-without).